# std::remove_if polymorphic std::unique_ptr from std::vector

Tags: c++, polymorphism, c++14

I have a hierarchy of three classes where `Derived` derives from `Selectable` and `Drawable`. Then I have a `std::vector` of `std::unique_ptr<Drawable>` which I fill with `Derived` objects.

I am *certain* that the vector will be filled only by objects which derive from both bases simultaneously.

The problem comes when I try to remove a certain element from the vector by using a pointer to `Selected`.

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <algorithm>

struct Selectable {
    virtual ~Selectable() = 0;
};
Selectable::~Selectable() = default;

struct Drawable {
    virtual ~Drawable() = 0;
};
Drawable::~Drawable() = default;

struct Derived : Selectable, Drawable {};

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Drawable>> vec;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        vec.push_back(std::make_unique<Derived>());
    }
    Selectable* selected = dynamic_cast<Selectable*>(vec[2].get());

    vec.erase(std::remove_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), 
        [selected](auto&& ptr) { 
            return ptr.get() == dynamic_cast<Drawable*>(selected); 
    }), vec.end());
}
```

Obviously, if I make `selected` to be a pointer to `Drawable`, everything is fine, but that is not my intention.

I am getting a run-time error which causes the program to crash. Why is this happening and how would I fix it?

Comment: which 'runtime_error'?

Comment: std::make_unique is from C++14. you should have tagged your question c++14

Comment: @SergeiKurenkov My bad, didn't cross my mind. Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The key problem lies in the way `std::remove_if` "removes" elements :

> Removing is done by shifting (by means of move assignment) the
>   elements in the range in such a way that the elements that are not to
>   be removed appear in the beginning of the range. Relative order of the
>   elements that remain is preserved and the physical size of the
>   container is unchanged. Iterators pointing to an element between the
>   new logical end and the physical end of the range are still
>   dereferenceable, **but the elements themselves have unspecified values**
>   (as per MoveAssignable post-condition).

So basically, you keep a raw pointer acquired by `auto ptr = vec[2].get()` , but no-one guaranteed that `ptr` remains valid. you are only guaranteed that `vec[2]` is valid. (the unique pointer which used to be in `vec[2]` before the filtering now lies between the new logical end and the physical end, in unspecified value).

In your example, when `std::remove_if` reaches the third element, the predicate returns `true` and `remove_if` calls `vec[2].get()`'s destructor. 
since you keep a raw pointer to it, you are using a pointer to an object which already is destroyed.

Comment: `reaches the second element` - [2] is a third element

Comment: I see, that makes sense, but how would I end up removing the element then?

Comment: @DeiDei use `std::find` + `std::vector::erase`

Answer (score 5):

The reason why your program crashes is that you call `dynamic_cast` for invalid pointer. It is easy to demonstrate just by adding output to your destructors and printing selected:

```
struct Selectable {
    virtual ~Selectable();
};
Selectable::~Selectable() {
  std::cout << "Selectable::~Selectable:" << this << std::endl;
};

struct Drawable {
    virtual ~Drawable();
};
Drawable::~Drawable() {
  std::cout << "Drawable::~Drawable:" << this << std::endl;
}

vec.erase(std::remove_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), 
    [selected](auto&& ptr) { 
        std::cout << "selected:" << selected << std::endl;
        return ptr.get() == dynamic_cast<Drawable*>(selected); 
}), vec.end());
```

This is a possible output:

```
$ ./a.exe
selected:0x3e3ff8
selected:0x3e3ff8
selected:0x3e3ff8
selected:0x3e3ff8
Drawable::~Drawable:0x3e3ffc
Selectable::~Selectable:0x3e3ff8
selected:0x3e3ff8
Segmentation fault
```

Calling `dynamic_cast` on an invalid pointer [is undefined behaviour](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast).

> Obviously if I make `selected` to be a pointer to `Drawable`, everything is fine, but that is not my intention.

In this situation you also have an invalid pointer but `dynamic_cast` is simply not generated by your compiler since it is not required. As a result of it in this case your program avoids crashing.

Answer (score 0):

When run under Valgrind, the first error I see is

```
Invalid read of size 8
   at 0x4CCE92D: __dynamic_cast (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.22)
   by 0x109139: _ZZ4mainENKUlOT_E_clIRSt10unique_ptrI8DrawableSt14default_deleteIS4_EEEEDaS0_ (43706186.cpp:27)
   by 0x10917B: _ZN9__gnu_cxx5__ops10_Iter_predIZ4mainEUlOT_E_EclINS_17__normal_iteratorIPSt10unique_ptrI8DrawableSt14default_deleteIS9_EESt6vectorISC_SaISC_EEEEEEbS2_ (predefined_ops.h:241)
   by 0x10902D: _ZSt11__remove_ifIN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPSt10unique_ptrI8DrawableSt14default_deleteIS3_EESt6vectorIS6_SaIS6_EEEENS0_5__ops10_Iter_predIZ4mainEUlOT_E_EEESE_SE_SE_T0_ (stl_algo.h:866)
   by 0x108F78: _ZSt9remove_ifIN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPSt10unique_ptrI8DrawableSt14default_deleteIS3_EESt6vectorIS6_SaIS6_EEEEZ4mainEUlOT_E_ESC_SC_SC_T0_ (stl_algo.h:937)
   by 0x108EBC: main (43706186.cpp:25)
 Address 0x5892dc0 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 16 free'd
   at 0x4A0A2DB: operator delete(void*) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
   by 0x109BFC: Derived::~Derived() (43706186.cpp:15)
   by 0x109D21: std::default_delete<Drawable>::operator()(Drawable*) const (unique_ptr.h:76)
   by 0x10A7C4: std::unique_ptr<Drawable, std::default_delete<Drawable> >::reset(Drawable*) (unique_ptr.h:347)
   by 0x10A39D: std::unique_ptr<Drawable, std::default_delete<Drawable> >::operator=(std::unique_ptr<Drawable, std::default_delete<Drawable> >&&) (unique_ptr.h:254)
   by 0x109062: _ZSt11__remove_ifIN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPSt10unique_ptrI8DrawableSt14default_deleteIS3_EESt6vectorIS6_SaIS6_EEEENS0_5__ops10_Iter_predIZ4mainEUlOT_E_EEESE_SE_SE_T0_ (stl_algo.h:868)
   by 0x108F78: _ZSt9remove_ifIN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPSt10unique_ptrI8DrawableSt14default_deleteIS3_EESt6vectorIS6_SaIS6_EEEEZ4mainEUlOT_E_ESC_SC_SC_T0_ (stl_algo.h:937)
   by 0x108EBC: main (43706186.cpp:25)
 Block was alloc'd at
   at 0x4A0921F: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
   by 0x10942E: std::_MakeUniq<Derived>::__single_object std::make_unique<Derived>() (unique_ptr.h:791)
   by 0x108DE2: main (43706186.cpp:21)
```

From this, we can see that one of the elements added to the array was deleted, but we still attempted the `dynamic_cast` in the lambda through the captured pointer (`selected`).

If we move the cast outside erase-remove call, then the `dynamic_cast` is performed only once, before the element is removed:

```
    auto const s2 = dynamic_cast<Drawable*>(selected);

    vec.erase(std::remove_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), 
        [s2](auto&& ptr) { 
            return ptr.get() == s2; 
    }), vec.end());
```

This version runs to completion with no warnings from Valgrind.

In passing, note that you can write the lambda to accept `const auto&`, as you don't intend to modify the elements.